# How can I use emoji characters on a Windows 8 PC without a touch screen?

Tags: windows-8, fonts

The Windows 8.x touch screen keyboard allows for use of many emoji characters, but how can these be accessed without a touch screen? I would've thought they should be available through Character Map, but that means I need to know the correct font in advance, or where they would show.

Does character Map support emoji, and if so, does it need to be from a specific font?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same on screen keyboard as for touch screen devices by doing: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog, and type **tabtip**.

This will then type into the current application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition zu Rowland Shaws answer, you can also perform a **right click on the taskbar** and tick **Show touch keyboard button** to make the touch keyboard available as a tray icon.

Comment: This does not address the question in the OP, whoch concerns **emojis**. Pls answer the question being asked, not the one to which you know the solution.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the touch keyboard is the tabtip.exe, so I still feel like having answered the question. It's a different path to the same tool, namely showing the touch keyboard, which allows the input of emojis.

Comment: @Striezel  from the question:-  "screen keyboard allows for use of many emoji characters, but how can these be accessed without a touch screen? "