# Can I use emojis on a Windows PC without a touch keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

Similar to [How can I use emoji characters on a Windows 8 PC without a touch screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/777977/how-can-i-use-emoji-characters-on-a-windows-8-pc-without-a-touch-screen) but for **Windows 10**. I have a bog standard PC with Windows 10 installed. I tried doing the same as the suggestion for Windows 8 but that doesn't seem to work.

Most tips you find out there speak of having a screen keyboard popping up, but I don't have such an icon in the task bar that would activate the touch keyboard. Is there any other way to get to the in-built emojis?

[image: screen shot of task bar]

Answer (score 6):

1. Right-click on your Taskbar

[image]

2. Select "Show Touch Keyboard button"
3. You should then see the following keyboard if you click the keyboard icon to the far right of your taskbar (left of the clock):

[image]

4. You can then click the smiley face to open the emoji keyboard.

Microsoft actually recommends you keep the touch keyboard for this exact reason. But like I said in my comment, I don't use emoji and thus have no use for the keyboard, hence why I have hid it. If you use emojis often, you may want to consider keeping it on your taskbar.

Comment: Be aware that certain keyboard layouts may not have the emoji button, you might have to switch layouts.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest Windows 10 Fall Creators update 1709, you can press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to bring up the emoji IME panel in which you can search for the emoji you want.

[image: A picture of the emoji IME]

Comment: Note that this only works if you are using the en-us (English, USA) keymap. Despite being a headline feature of the Windows 10 FCU, it literally isn't supported for any other keymap, straight from Microsoft's mouth. Even with the very similar English, UK keyboard, the shortcuts do nothing, and still do nothing months after the update. Microsoft and Windows 10 are inexplicable lately.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click in the black space on your taskbar, an option comes up saying Show Touch Keyboard Button. Pressing that button brings up the Touch Keyboard.